# 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, pygame

I get the message : 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'update'. But as you can see, i have an update function in the code. wha did i wrong? I looked around but i didn't fina a simular question.

```
class Createparticle:
    def __init__(self, xx, yy,img):
        self.x = xx
        self.y = yy
        self.img = img
        self.particlelist = []
        self.verzoegerung = 0        
        self.scale_k = 0.1
        self.img = scale(img, self.scale_k)
        self.alpha = 255
        self.alpha_rate = 3
        self.alive = True
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 4 + random.randint(-10, 10) / 10
        self.k = 0.01 * random.random() * random.choice([-1, 1])

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.vx += self.k
        self.y -= self.vy
        self.vy *= 0.99
        self.scale_k += 0.005
        self.alpha -= self.alpha_rate           
        self.img = scale(self.img, self.scale_k)
        self.img.set_alpha(self.alpha)
        self.particlelist = [i for i in self.particlelist if i.alive]      
        self.verzoegerung += 1
        if self.verzoegerung % 2 == 0:
            self.verzoegerung = 0
            self.particlelist.append(self.img)        
        for i in self.particlelist:
            i.update()
 
    def draw(self):
        for i in self.particlelist:
            screen.blit(self.img, self.img.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y)))
  
createparticle = Createparticle(500,300,basisbild)

while True:       
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    createparticle.update()
    createparticle.draw()      
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: The problem is `i.update()`. `i` is an item from `self.particlelist`. `self.particlelist` is an image (`pygame.Surface`). A `pygame.Surface` has no `update` methode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `i.update()`. `i` is an element from `self.particlelist`. In your case `self.particlelist` is an image (`pygame.Surface`). A `pygame.Surface` object has no update `method`. Probably `i` should not be a `pygame.Surface`, but you add `pygame.Surface` objects to the list:

> ```py
> self.particlelist.append(self.img)
> ```

So this line of code is obviously wrong and should be like this instead (note: `Particle` is a guess of mine, but I don't know how you named your classes.):

```py
self.particlelist.append(Particle(self.img))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a list of surfaces called particlelist, in your update function you are calling the update function on each item in that list. Since theses are of the 'surface' type they don't have a update function. This is where the error is coming from.

Comment: I don't understand it. What i have to change in the code?